# Rails controllers, rendering view from different controller, saving form inputs and error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Two controllers: Users and Tasks.
Main page for Users = Users/user_id.
Form on main page used to input data into tasks model.
This process handled by the Tasks Controller.
Successful input: redirect and load tasks from database, OK, all working.
Unsuccessful input, just need to refresh main page so we keep form input and specialised (non-flash) error messages

I can't seem to get the Tasks Controller to deliver the original page. Error is Missing template users/1(which is the correct syntax if I were to visit in my browser).

Should I be calling an action and passing params? Any help for this beginner would be really appreciated.

```
def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)
        if @task.save
        flash[:success] = "New task created!"
        redirect_to user_url(current_user)
        else
        flash[:error] = "Task not saved! Please see guidance by form labels"
        render "users/#{current_user.id}"
        end
end

private

     def task_params
        params.require(:task).permit(:label, :address, :content)
     end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

users/1 is not a template, it's a path.  users/show is the template in this case.

mind that the only reason to use render is to render a template in the scope of your current controller action rather than the normal one.
i.e. you probably need to have @user etc set, or the users/show template will be upset about missing variables.

In this case it might be easier just to redirect_to user_path(id) and allow the users/#show controller action set up the @user variable etc.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have used 'render users/show' and 'render users#show' and redirect_to user path and they all re-issue the page. I have worked around it with the flash message but I would rather the user did not go anywhere so we could see the form input and error messages from Active Record.

Comment: the quick answer (and I avoid giving the quick answers.) is replace   'render "users/#{current_user.id}"' with 'render "users/show" ' [railsguides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller) can be helpful with these things.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. This fixed a problem I was having also. Now the error messages render just fine.